# Reading from a file and writing to a file in perl

Tags: perl

I have a file to read as show below. I need to read the data from read.txt and write into a different file write.txt as shown belo. there were so many other values in read.txt in similar way. I need to write them into write.txt. please help.

read.txt

```
value: length
var: cm
data: 10

value: weight
var: lb
data: 145

value:currency
var: dollar
data: 1000
```

write.txt

```
#Header Info, length_cm, weight_lb, currency_dollar
#data, 10, 145, 1000
```

Comment: So... what is 10 cm long, weighs 145 pounds and costs 1000 dollars??

Comment: they are just some random values given . I think that data doesnt mean anything

Comment: Too broad.  Figure something out yourself before posting here.

Comment: Yep, post what have you tried if u expect some help. Like reading the file, split it by `:` then saving it back to a new file on your given format.

Comment: You only need to be able to read from standard input (or file names presented on the command line) and write to standard output (which is pretty easy in Perl), and you can then use the shell to run `perl script.pl read.txt > write.txt` with the advantage that you can omit the output redirection and see what's produced on the terminal as it is produced.  What have you got so far?

Comment: [You are expected to put forth some effort.](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`$/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24/)

```
my @attr_names;
my %rec;

local $/ = '';
while (<>) {
   my %attr;
   while (/^([^:]+):\s*(.*)/mg) {
      $attr{$1} = $2;
   }

   warn("Missing value"), next if !$attr{value};
   warn("Missing var"),   next if !$attr{var};
   warn("Missing data"),  next if !$attr{data};

   my $attr_name = "$attr{value}_$attr{var}";
   push @attr_names, $attr_name;

   $rec{$attr_name} = $attr{data};
}

print(join(',', @rec{@attr_names}), "\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. it should append to the data already there in the write.txt, I mean the new data should get appended after #Header Info and the data should append after #data

Comment: Nothing you can't handle.